# Show results in a datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview, project

I have results from 5 methodes . I want to sort results from each methods and then show them in 5 column in datagridview.
Can U help me ?

Comment: update question with how you get results from 5 methods and what they return

Answer (score 0):

You may want to add them in Lists:

```
List<int> Results1 = new List<int>();
List<int> Results2 = new List<int>();
```

And then in a loop like, you can add them in datagridview.

```
for(int i=0;i<Results1.count;i++)
{
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = Results1[i]; 
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = Results2[i]; 
}
```

I suggest you search datatable in c# also.Hope it helps.